# HTML/CSS - is is possible to have a html website with multiple pages - but only one menu (indentical) that can be called?

Tags: html, css, menu, call

To start off with I can only use HTML and/or CSS. I do not have the capacity to use PHP or JavaScript?

I have researched an iFrame, but I'm not sure if it is possible to have a dropdown menu with an iFrame?

Comment: For this you would just need your different .html files in the same directory, and then you can reference those files in your menu with relative paths like "/path/to/file.html".

You are better off just copy pasting the html of the menu into each file, instead of using a wonky iFrame

Comment: For php you need a server but for JS you can use it easily

Comment: I think the poster wants the menu to be one "source of truth" shared across multiple pages -- as one might do in PHP/MVC with an include or through a shared JS file.
The reasons for doing so are obvious: you don't have to maintain the same menu multiple times.
For the limitations you face, an iframe probably is the best it's going to get -- perhaps one on the left or right, with a tree-structure. You won't be able to make a shared menu which pops out and covers the main content area as the content for each iframe would be constrained by the iframe it's in

Comment: Check out this demo, the downside is it looks to require JS, but give it a look: http://www.menucool.com/vertical/html-menu-in-separate-file.  It may give you some ideas or lead you in the right direction.

Comment: I think that with all the time you spend looking for a way to do this without using javascript/PHP/something else, you could take the time to learn how to do it a more effective way. I think it is worth the time investment.

Comment: @labago, I will eventually have multiple pages, so I am trying now to cut down the work load, so if there is any way iframe would work i would try my best to use it.

Answer (score 0):

There's a very old-hat way of doing this called framesets, beware this is very old, doesn't look great and I'm not sure if it'll work well with dropdown menus e.t.c.

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_frameset.asp has more on it.

Other than that the only thing I can think of is using PHP includes (which in you mentioned you don't have the capacity for) although I can go into detail about using PHP includes if need be.

Alternatively just repeating the menu code in each html page is the only other option as far as I know.

Comment: I would not recommend this method. It is not supported in HTML 5.

Comment: Yup i wouldn't use it either, I'd personally use PHP includes, but it's still technically viable - browsers support it and it's up to OP to make that call.

Answer (score 0):

I personlally don't know a way which is just done with a HTML and CSS. But there is an easy way with PHP.

1. You make a file (nav.php) where you put your navigation stuff into it.
   (Don't forget the php tags):

Now you can include the file in any HTML Document:

```
<?php include_once "filePath"; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

With just html&css, I only know copy&pasting. But with your wording, it sounds like you want just one menu like menu.html and linking it onto the multiple pages where you if you were to change the menu, you only need to change it in one section and don't need to copy and paste the rest. Since you want 1 single menu and link it to the multiple pages, I suggest the php way as Lorenz mentioned.
http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_includes.asp

...or another way I saw someone else do it is somewhere in this video by DevTips:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nZoUA-98fL4

its something like `{% filename %}` but idk what lang. or whatever that's suppose to be. He just made his code look so much messier to me that I didn't bother looking into it.

Comment: thanks for your help @reddtoric, but the server I am using is very basic and is unable to support PHP/JavaScript. It will only support HTML/CSS.